# Use to switches to provide necessary voltage

Tags: design

I am wondering how to work this out and have been busting my head over it over night.

In fact, I was working on this till 03:00.

In all, my shed is solar powered. I am only powering some LED 1W lights (8 of them).

I have a dusk/dawn switch (SW1) that will activate the light circuit on.

I have another switch (SW2) in series in the door. This will switch the lights on upon opening the door.

Now the tricky part. I have a bypass switch (SW3) to switch the lights on during the day time, should there's the need to.

This switch is in series with the door switch (release to make connection).

Now the problem here is, I might want the lights on if I am to close the door but this won't happen with the current wiring as when the door switch (SW2) is pushed in, it breaks the circuit.

What I then did was to add another switch (SW4) in series with SW3.

But what if I leave the shed and forget the lights on?

I thought, why not connect a small 12V buzzer that will power on when I open the door (SW2)?

But I need only to provide it half the voltage as the other half will be provided by SW4.

Why this setup? Because if I am to supply the whole 12V to the buzer, SW2 would provide it, so I need to cut it in half so that the initial half is provided by the SW4 and the remaining voltage provided when the door is opened therefore reminding you that the lights are on.

Makes sense?

Can this be achieved as I am thinking by adding a resistor to the end of SW2 and SW4?

I'll work on a circuit drawing to help better.

Many thanks in advance.

Regards,
Albert

[image: Buzzer circuit]

Comment: I have just noticed that the 6V at the end of each resistor are connected in parallel so I won't have 12V will I? I will be just increasing current? How to connect the 6V in series?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create some logical functions here. This can be done with switches of various types, but not the way you've shown it.

You want the lights to come on if the door is open OR `SW4` is closed.

You want the buzzer to activate if the door is open AND `SW4` is closed.

This requires `SW4` to have two poles:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCu6tt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that if either `SW1` or `SW3` is activated while `SW4` is on, the buzzer will sound. To prevent this, you'll need to add a diode:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhzTGK.png)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the resistors, you need a new SW\$2\$, and this should work:

SW\$2\$ is a double-pole single-throw normally closed switch, and when the door opens and SW\$2\$B closes, the buzzer will sound unconditionally.

[image]

Comment: He wants the buzzer to sound only if `SW4` is on when the door is opened, not every time the door is opened.

Comment: Hi Dave, EM Fields.
Many thanks you guys for the help provided.
I have done my level 2 in electrical installations and am finishing my level 3.
Having said that I only covered circuit (electronics) in very little detail.
Had to implement a diode on this setup but it took me time to figure it out.
I'm going to have a go at using circuitlab as I am using excel to do my circuits, Lol...
Again you guys, I can't thank you enough for the time you took and given to me to help.
Regards and a very nice weekend to all.
Albert

Comment: Hi Dave.
I have been looking at your drawing and I don't think we are quite there yet.
SW1 = Dusk/Dawn switch
SW2 = Door open switch = lights on (SW2 will not turn light on if SW1 hasn't yet been activated.
I might have the need for light during day time. So, I have a bypass switch (SW3) to ignore SW1. So SW2 will work with SW3.
But say I am to close the door. SW2 will cut out so, I need another switch. SW4 will bypass SW1 and SW3 are ignored. I now need to work with SW2 and SW4. SW4 will turn light and SW2 will activate buzzer if door is opened, a reminder that light is on.
Many thanks.
Alber

Comment: All tested live and it works wonders.
Thanks to you all.
Regards,
Albert